# Pattern to avoid Cyclic calls

Tags: c++11, design-patterns

I have Policy class as below:

```
interface IPolicy
{
public:
virtual void func1() = 0;
}

class CPolicy : public IPolicy
{
public:
void func1() override { // do something }
}
```

And I have Utility Class as

```
class Util {
public:
void func1() {
if( policy != nullptr ) policy->func1(); // customized behavior

// default behavior
}

}
```

Now problem is, consider policy implementation have some condition and if that condition fails, policy calls default implementation ( this is one of the scenario, there can be multiple combinations )

```
class CPolicy : public IPolicy
{
public:
void func1() override { 
 if( condition ) 
 {
    // customized logic
 }
 pDefaultUtil->func1();
}
}
```

Now if you see this implementation it will endup in cyclic calls.

To solve such problem, I introduced another function in IPolicy contract.

```
interface IPolicy
{
public:
virtual void func1() = 0;
virtual bool ShouldUsePolicy() = 0;
}


class CPolicy : public IPolicy
{
public:
void func1() override { 
 if( condition ) 
 {
    // customized logic
 }
 usePolicy = false;
 pDefaultUtil->func1();
usePolicy = true;
// other logic continues.
}

bool ShouldUsePolicy() override { return usePolicy; }
private:
bool usePolicy { true };
}
```

and Util class is modified as :

```
class Util {
public:
void func1() {
if( policy != nullptr && policy->ShouldUsePolicy() ) policy->func1(); // customized behavior

// default behavior
}

}
```

With these changes, everything will work as expected, but I am not happy with this design. I don't want to depend on whether Policy is setting usePolicy variable properly or not. If any call comes from Policy to Default implementation then I should be able to ignore policy.

Is there any good pattern / solution for such problems?

Answer (score 0):

`Policy` class should not do anything more than what it is responsible for (Single Responsibility Principle). A simple change would be to make `func1` return a bool value and let the `Utility` class decide what to do when it returns false.

```
class IPolicy
{
public:
  virtual bool func1() = 0;
  virtual ~IPolicy() {};
}


class CPolicy : public IPolicy
{
public:
  void func1() override { 
    if( condition ) 
    {
      // customized logic
      return true;
    }
    return false;
};

class Util {
public:
  void func1() {
    assert (policy);
    if (! policy->func1()) {
      // Call the default action as seen
      // fit by the Util class
    }
  }
};
```